# pip --no-dependencies flag appears to be ignored

Tags: pip

Executing `pip install --no-dependencies pyarrow==4.0.1`,

I see

```
Looking in indexes: ...
Collecting pyarrow==4.0.1
  Using cached ...
  Installing build dependencies ...
```

Why is it still "Installing build dependencies"? Installing the numpy dependency (somehow it started compiling it) failed shortly afterwards, so I'd like to skip that step.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7444#issuecomment-562814489

Comment: You cannot build the project without **build** dependencies.